How do I add a large number of files into a Github repository?
I have a folder of code and assets (mostly assets) for a website I'm making that has a lot of files in it. By a lot, I mean literally thousands of files. I want to put the contents of this folder into Github, however due to the sheer enormity of the folder, it has proved challenging.
I have tried using uploading the files to Github directly, however that didn't work as it did not add the files from selected folders. I am currently trying to add them in using VS Code, by copying the files from the VS Code window that has the local files into another VS Code window that has the repository open (using the "remote repositories" extension), however that is taking a long time, and I'm not sure if it is working, as the explorer tab is not updating to reflect the changes listed in the source control tab.
If someone could tell me how to add my files to the repository, that would be wonderful!
PS: I really don't understand how to use git on the command line, which is why none of the other answers to similar questions work for me.

Well, the command line really would be how I'd tackle this. Something along the lines of git add <directory>, git commit -m "Add directory", git push origin main, where origin is the name of the remote (check with git remote show), and main is the branch name (check with git branch).

I'm going to try that, because vscode still hasn't finished copying the files and I'm getting desperate. Probably going to mess up horribly tho.

Maybe check GitHub to see what's arrived already? Is there any kind of progress visible somewhere? If VS Code is busy, maybe wait a little. How much data are we talking overall?

7,888 files, 1.40 GB

It might be close to finishing; vscode says there are 7535 pending changes. It's been hanging there for a while, though.

I would recommend investing some time learning the git command line interface, it's a skill that will serve you well to have in the future. The CLI, once you understand it, lets you have much more precise control over what you're doing.
